# Binding Checkbox object from View to Controller

Tags: spring, arraylist, checkbox, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new at Spring Boot and I face huge difficulties for binding object from a view with ThymeLeaf to a List in my Controller.
Explanation : I got a Form for create events. In this Form there are checkboxes generated dynamically with a List of "Enfant" (`listEnfant`) stored in the database :

GET REQUEST

```
@Controller
public class EventController {

@RequestMapping(value="/createEvent",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String Affichercreationcotisation(Model model,Enfant enfant){

    List<Enfant> listEnfant = gardeMetier.findEnfantfamille();
    model.addAttribute("listEnfant", listEnfant);

    List<String> ListEnfants = new ArrayList<>(0);
    model.addAttribute("listEnfantsChoisis", ListEnfants);

    return "eventForm";
}
```

When I run the Application there is no problem with the GET Request I got the checkboxes which are expected

As you can see i created an empty List which I could use to store selected checkboxes objects

HTML

```
    <th:block th:each="e :${listEnfant}">                       
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="" />   
    <label th:text="${e.name}"></label>
    </th:block>
```

I don't know and don't find (or understand) what to do with my post request and how to configure the `th:field` to put the selected checkboxes objects in a List when the Form is submitted

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveEvent",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEvent()   {
}
```

I hope someone will help me because I'm looking for the solution for hours now :(

Comment: Hope it will help you [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957738/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-binding-list-with-check-boxes)